# Change the link of SharePoint logo

Tags: sharepoint-online

By default links in the SharePoint logo goes to the parent site ? I need to change the link to a different location. Will this be possible in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- Go to site setting
- Click Welcome Page

[image]

- Give the new link there

[image]

- Click OK

And logo link will update

**Edit:**

For **`Welcome Page`** option enabled, the **`SharePoint Server Publishing`** feature must be activated in your site.

Comment: looks easy. i dont want to change the structure or the home page i just want to change link of the logo to a particular page. can this be achieved with the above

Comment: yes. It will not change the structure. It just update the link on the sharepoint logo

Comment: i couldnt find this option in my site setting. it is only available in the site collection. when i tried to add it gives me an error message "The specified welcome page is not valid or does not exist within the current site."

Comment: I guess your publishing feature is not activated. For the error message there might be problem with page url.