# How to change SP 2016 link to logo

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

How can I change the link to the logo of a SharePoint 2016 site?  Currently, there is a logo but it isn't even linked up.  The masterpage has been slightly branded using design manager.  I know it's possible but I can't find the settings?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps :

- Go to site setting
- Click Welcome Page

[image]

- Give the new link there

[image]

- Click OK

And logo link will update

**Edit:**

For **`Welcome Page`** option enabled, the **`SharePoint Server Publishing`** feature must be activated in your site.

Reference URL :

[Change the link of SharePoint logo](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/202514/87201)

**Update**

In order to get the above "welcome page" setting, we need to activate the below two features:

- Activate **"SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"** feature in site collection level.
- Activate **"SharePoint Server Publishing"** feature in site level.

After activating the above two features also if we don't get the "welcome page" option under "Look and Feel" section of site setting page - we can directly access the below URL and get the setting:

```
https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSiteTestByPnP/_layouts/15/AreaWelcomePage.aspx
```

Comment: That's what I initially tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Verify SharePoint server publishing feature is enabled in your site - if already enabled but still not getting this option, try to deactivate and re-activate back.

Comment: After activating the features, if you still don't get the option, directly you can access the below page URL: /_layouts/15/AreaWelcomePage.aspx      please see my updated answer.

Comment: We have some customizations that I am afraid to lose if I deactivate the publishing feature. AreaWelcomePage.aspx doesn't exist for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using IE F12 developer to select the logo, and check the HTML element.

[image]

And try to a link to the logo using JavaScript code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").attr("href","/");
})
</script>
```